# Cannot get $get method called automatically in angularjs provider

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, get, provider

Here's the piece of code I'm writing in angularjs 1.5.5:

```
export default angular.module(
  'myApp', [])
  .provider('finder', function finderProvider() {
    this.$get = $get;

    function $get() {
      console.log('GET');
    }

    this.callMe = () => {
      console.log('CALLED');
    };
  })
  .config(['finderProvider', function(finderProvider) {
    //finderProvider.$get();
    finderProvider.callMe();
  }])
  .name;
```

I'm trying to inject a service into this provider later. I read on documentation that I can only inject a service inside a provider using $get() method. However, I cannot call $get() automatically. The only way I can get this working is to call $get() manually in the section where I commented the call. But it doesn't seem right to me to call $get manually.

In this example only 'CALLED' is getting logged. Any idea what I'm missing here?

EDIT. I tried to use another syntax using the arrow function, but got the same result:

```
.provider('finder', () => {
    return {
      $get: () => {
        console.log('GET');
      },
      callMe: () => {
        console.log('CALLED');
      }
    };
  })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a fat arrow treats `this` differently than a function does.  What happens if you update your first example to a fat arrow as well?

Comment: @DavidL I tried to change it using the arrow functions, but I get the same results. I updated my original post with my new changes.

Comment: There has to be more going on than what you've posted here then.  There's no reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: @DavidL Thanks. Actually there's nothing wrong with my code. I was using this provider as config(). That's why $get wasn't being used.

Answer (score 2):

Angular services are lazily instantiated.

Service provider constructor function is called when it is injected during config phase (`config` block or other provider).

`$get` is called when service instance is injected after config phase.

In the example above `finder` service isn't injected anywhere, service instance isn't created and `$get` function isn't called.

Comment: In my example I'm injecting the provide in the line with: .config(['finderProvider', function(finderProvider). It looks like AngularJS adds "Provider" suffix automatically. Should I inject my provider using another syntax?

Comment: `finderProvider` and `finder` are two different things. The first one is service provider, the other one is service instance. `finderProvider` can be injected to `config` block, `finder` can be injected to `run` block, not crosswise.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I was only using my provider in config(), that's why $get() wasn't used. I found it a bit confusing on why it raised an error, when $get() wasn't there. Because when $get() was there, it wasn't used. I wish I knew this earlier.

Comment: This may be confusing, because `provider` is the only place where you define both `finderProvider` provider (as constructor function) and `finder` instance (as $get function), and they are different kinds of injectables.